# how can I use a jenkins job to loop another jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a requirement where I need 2 Jenkins job, One job to take user parameters (eg: user chooses number 10 which means I need to run second job 10 times)
second job will be the actual execution of test automation.

The loop will continue irrespective of the result (pass/fail) of previous iteration

just trying to represent this as a Snippet,

Job A :

User input = 10
for(num<=10){
Job B(num)
}

Job B : 
execute(num)

P.S: If there is a solution where I can achieve this in a single job, Please suggest

Comment: Fairly simple using pipeline jobs. Did you check this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins upstream/downstream concept, please refer below url:-

[Jenkins Upstream/Downstream Linking](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-use-jenkins-for-job-chaining-and-visualizations/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it:

You can use the same solution for Linux and Windows machine (in windows write cmd syntax and in Linux Bash)

You create a loop for example in Bash:

## !/bin/bash

for i in {1..5}
do
curl 
done

If you do not know CURL please use the link below.
https://serverfault.com/questions/888176/how-to-trigger-jenkins-job-via-curl-command-remotely